# How to embed large amount of documents from one collection, into documents of another? (Overcoming lack of join)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I currently have this solution to the lack of join in MongoDB, where I am querying two collections to find out the sold information for 3 types of stock.

However I would prefer just to have one collection embedded into the other. Is this possible?

For instance a stock document would have an embedded sold document, which also had the same Stock_index before they were de-normalised (queried separately).

Both collections are fairly large (10,000+ documents each).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of both documents?

Comment: You should not. There are various ways of overcoming the lack of joins with carefully crafted data models. Over embedding, however, is [a good way to get you into trouble](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/)